# Html 5 required on radio button wil not reset

Tags: html, forms

Why won't an html5 required on radio button group reset with form reset button if it was selected. for example you have a radio button group in a form with the html5 required set if you select one of the radio buttons then click the reset form button it doesn't reset the radio button group required validation so even though the form was reset. So basically you click submit button without selecting anything the radio buttons are given an outline in red then you select one and click reset you are then able to submit the form without selecting a radio button? any help on why it does this would be greatly appreciated. I may misunderstand how its supposed to work.
Simple test

```
   <html>
   <form>
   <input type="radio" name="test" required>
   <input type="radio" name="test" required>
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
   <input type="reset" value="cancel">
   </form>
   </html>
```

Comment: How can a radio button be required? It's either checked or not checked, and defaults to not checked.

Comment: I'm using it for some jquery stuff to display and disable certain fields I just couldn't figure out why the required wasn't working thanks to @XYZ I found that it was the browser that was causing the issue. I needed it to validate before the form was submitted  cause they need to make a choice to display a certain part of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using same name for the radio buttons.If you give the same name only one radio button of the can be checked.And so it passes the Validation

Example : Different name for radio buttons.

```html
<form>
   <input type="radio" name="test" required>
   <input type="radio" name="test2" required>
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
   <input type="reset" value="cancel">
   </form>
```

Example : Same name for radio buttons.

```html
<form>
       <input type="radio" name="test" required>
       <input type="radio" name="test" required>
       <input type="submit" value="submit">
       <input type="reset" value="cancel">
</form>
```

Comment: Ok so that just takes it out of the radio button group the one radio button that was selected doesn't reset the validation? so now you click a radio button and click reset it doesn't reset that radio button validation? everything works like I want it to until the user selects one then tries to reset the form it doesn't do another check after form reset?

Comment: @i didnt get you.Could you please make a fiddle

Comment: ok so when you run the code snippet above click submit. click a radio button then click cancel then submit the form it doesn't check the button because it doesn't give you the outline so it submits the form.

Comment: @Helleos in first snippet or second

Comment: I need it to check both buttons again does it not work this way?

Comment: You can check the first snippet.In that both the radio buttons must be sumbitted for the form to submit

Comment: doesn't matter what code snippet select both of the radio buttons then hit cancel and hit submit it doesn't check again?

Comment: @Helleos I dont konw what i am missing.If select both click cancel and hit submit  it is validtaing the radio again in the first snippet

Comment: so it shows you the red outlines again and wont submit the form after you did the above? it may be something on my company computer that's causing an issue if its working for you.

Comment: @Helleos So which  browser are you using?

Comment: Internet Explorer 11

Comment: @Helleos I have checked this in firefox and chorme latest version.But i  for IE i'm not sure about this.

Comment: Well thanks for your help its a browser thing tried it on edge and it works ill see if I cant find a way to make it work in IE 11 thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give them different value attributes (but the same name so it's clear that those are two different options for the same "question" and only one of them should be selectable):

```html
<html>
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="1" required>1 
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="2" required>2<br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
  <input type="reset" value="cancel">
</form>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried this . Shouldn't the validation reset? I also set the one to checked but I need them to be unselected or checked. if you set the one as selected does it even check for false values?

Comment: I don't understand your comment... "Shouldn't the validation reset? "...? "if you set the one as selected does it even check for false values" ?

Comment: In your original example and also in the answer you marked as correct, the radio input tags don't have any values, therefore these examples are wihtout any purpose and completely useless in real-world applications - you can't derive an output from them...

Comment: I don't need a value I'm using the buttons in jquery there is a use for them just not to get a value I ended up just doing some validation with some jquery and JavaScript thank you for your response though. I just wanted to figure out why html 5 required wasn't resetting on form reset I just gave a simple example and I didn't test in other browsers because it's for just one browser our cyber security blocks every other browser